# RClone / Bash - Loop through and download all files in directory individually

Tags: bash

I have an issue that I am completely unable to figure out.

I've got RClone setup and running on CentOS, I am trying to write a script to do the following

- List all files in directory (rclone ls MsOneDrive:/Dashcam/Saved)
- Download each file one at a time
- Run a command on each file
- Re-upload the file
- Delete the original

When I execute

```
rclone ls MsOneDrive:/Dashcam/Saved
```

I get a longer version of the following. Where, the number is the file size, and the second part is the filename.

E.G. 
"filesize filename.AVI"

```
511810664 00200367.AVI
509582440 01560041.AVI
 86225016 03510005.AVI
  8389816 03580007.AVI
503356520 05220203.AVI
502537320 06320079.AVI
508238952 06320080.AVI
```

Is there any way to parse this into a foreach loop or something similar that would let me perform those operations inside the loop?

Something along the lines of (ignoring the syntax of the foreach loop)

```
#!/bin/bash
foreach {i} (rclone ls MsOneDrive:/Dashcam/Saved)
    rclone copy $i <local>
    localOperation 
    rclone copy <local> <remote>
    rclone rm <remote>
 fi
```

Comment: do the files really have spaces in their names, i.e. `508238952 06320080.AVI` ? Please update your Q with this info and **don't** respond in comments. (Then I can delete this comment). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r size name; do
    rclone copy $name <local>
    (( $(stat -c %s <local>) == size )) || { echo ERROR; exit; }

    localOperation 
    rclone copy <local> <remote>
    rclone rm <remote>
done < <(rclone ls MsOneDrive:/Dashcam/Saved)
```

One advantage of doing this is you could compute total:

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
while read -r size name; do
    ((total+=size))
    ....
done < <(rclone ls MsOneDrive:/Dashcam/Saved)
printf "Total processed: %u.\n" $total
```

Comment: You may have to use quotes and/or double-quotes if *names* could contain spaces!